Invalid device flow scope “https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly”
"Invalid device flow scope" “https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly”
When sending request to Google API? Does anyone know the reason?
The steps are:

Create TV and device type project in console.cloud.google
Set right OAuth credentials
Send request with right client id and scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" to https://accounts.google.com/o/auth2/device/code.
Get invalid scope back, but if setting scope to “https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts”, 200 OK is gotten with device_code, user_code ...

enter image description here>
Above is postman`s screenshot.
I checked the document here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device It said only limited scopes allowed. But why "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts" works well, but "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" doesn`t.
Does anyone meet this kind of issue?
Do you know whether "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" is blocked by OAuth2.0 for TV and limited input?
